# Relative consistency of PA and some type theories

Tags: type-theory, proof-theory

For a type theory, by consistency, I mean that it has a type which is not inhabited. From the strong normalization of the lambda cube, it follows that system $F$ and system $F_\omega$ are consistent. MLTT + inductive types also has a normalization proof. However, these should all be powerful enough to construct a model of PA, which proves that PA is consistent from these theories. System $F$ is [quite powerful](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/can-we-prove-weak-normalization-for-system-f-by-induction-on-a-transfinite-ordin), so I expect it to be able to prove the consistency of PA by constructing a model using Church numerals. MLTT + IT has a natural numbers inductive type and should prove consistency as well.

This all implies that the normalization proofs for these theories can't be internalized in PA. So:

1. Can system $F$, system $F_\omega$, and MLTT + IT actually prove the consistency of PA?
2. If they can, then what metatheory is needed to prove normalization for system $F$, $F_\omega$, and MLTT+IT?
3. Is there a good reference for the proof theory of type theories in general, or for some of these type theories in particular?

Comment: In System F you won't get an induction principle for your Church numerals so they're out of the equations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer to your question 1 is *no*, but for perhaps subtle reasons.

First of all, System $F$ and $F_\omega$ **cannot express the first-order theory of arithmetic**, and even less the consistency of $\mathrm{PA}$.

Secondly, and this is really surprising, $\mathrm{PA}$ can actually prove consistency of both those systems! This is done using the so-called **proof-irrelevant model**, which interprets types as sets $\in\{\varnothing,\{\bullet\}\}$, where $\bullet$ is some dummy element representing an inhabitant of a non-empty type. Then one can write down simple rules for the operation of $\rightarrow$ and $\forall$ on such types rather easily to get a model for system $F$, in which the type $\forall X.X$ is interpreted by $\varnothing$. One can do a similar thing for $F_\omega$, using a bit more care to interpret higher kinds as finite functions spaces.

There's an apparent paradox here, where $\mathrm{PA}$ can prove consistency of these seemingly powerful systems, but not (as I'll show in a moment) normalization.

The missing ingredient here is **realizability**. Realizability is a way to make certain programs correspond to certain propositions, typically in arithmetic. I won't go into the details here, but if a program $p$ realizes a proposition $\phi$, written $p\Vdash \phi$, then we have a certain piece of evidence for $\phi$, in particular if $p$ is normalizing, then $p\not\Vdash\bot$. We have:

> Theorem: If $\phi$ is a theorem of 2nd order arithmetic $\mathrm{PA}_2$, then there is some closed term $t$ of system $F$ such that $$ t\Vdash\phi$$

*This* theorem can be proven in $\mathrm{PA}$, and so we have
$$\mathrm{PA}\vdash F\mbox{ is normalizing}\Rightarrow\mbox{$\mathrm{PA}_2$ is consistent} $$
and Gödel's argument applies (and $\mathrm{PA}$ cannot prove normalization of system $F$). It's useful to note that the reverse implication holds as well, so we have an exact characterization of the proof-theoretic power needed to prove normalization of system $F$.

There is a similar story for system $F_\omega$, which, I believe, corresponds to higher arithmetic $\mathrm{PA}_\omega$.

---

Finally, we have the tricky case of MLTT with inductive types. Here again a somewhat subtle issue arises. Certainly here we can express the consistency of $\mathrm{PA}$, so that isn't an issue, and there is no proof-irrelevant model, as we can prove that the type $\mathrm{Nat}$ has at least 2 elements (an infinite amount of distinct elements, in fact).

However we run into a surprising fact of higher-order intuitionistic theories: $\mathrm{HA}_\omega$, the higher-order version of Heyting Arithmetic is **conservative** over $\mathrm{HA}$! In particular, we cannot prove consistency of $\mathrm{PA}$, (which is equivalent to that of $\mathrm{HA}$). An intuitive reason for this is that intuitionistic function spaces do not allow you to quantify over arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{N}$, since all definable functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ must be computable.

In particular, I don't think you can prove consistency of $\mathrm{PA}$ if you add only natural numbers to MLTT without universes. I do believe adding either universes or "stronger" inductive types (like ordinal types) will give you enough power though, but I'm afraid I have no reference for this. With universes, the argument seems quite simple though, since you have enough set theory to build a model of $\mathrm{HA}$.

---

Finally, references for the proof theory of type systems: there's really a gap in the literature here I think, and I would relish a clean treatment of all these subjects (in fact, I dream of writing it myself some day!). In the meantime:

- The proof-irrelevant model is explained [here](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Benjamin.Werner/publis/cc.pdf) by Miquel and Werner, though they do it for the Calculus of Constructions, which complicates matters somewhat.
- The realizability argument is sketched in the classic [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf) of Girard, Taylor and Lafont. I think they also sketch the proof-irrelevant model, and a great deal of useful things besides. It's probably the first reference to read.
- The conservativity argument of higher-order Heyting arithmetic can be found in the elusive second volume of *Constructivism in Mathematics* by Troelstra & van Dalen (see [here](http://store.elsevier.com/Constructivism-in-Mathematics-Vol-2/A_S_-Troelstra/isbn-9780080955100/)). Both volumes are extremely informative, but quite difficult to read for a novice, IMHO. It also somewhat avoids "modern" type theory subjects, which is unsurprising given the books' age.

---

An additional question in the comments was about the exact consistency strength/normalization strength of MLTT+Inductives. I don't have a precise answer here, but certainly the answer depends on the number of universes and the nature of the inductive families allowed. Rathjen explores this question in the excellent paper [*The Strength of some Martin-Lof Type theories*](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/typeOHIO.pdf).

Wrt normalization, the basic idea is that if, for 2 theories $\cal{T}$ and $\cal{U}$, we have
$$\mathrm{PA}\vdash\mathrm{Con}(\cal{T})\Rightarrow\mathrm{Con}(\cal{U}) $$

then, **generally**

$$\mathrm{PA}\vdash \mbox{1-$\mathrm{Con}$}(\cal{T})\Rightarrow\mathrm{Norm}(\cal{U}) $$

where 1-$\mathrm{Con}$ is [1-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) and $\mathrm{Norm}$ is (weak) normalization.

MLTT + the type of natural numbers (and recursion) is a conservative extension of $\mathrm{HA}_\omega$, which is proven in Besson [*Recursive Models for Constructive Set Theories*](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0003484382900031/1-s2.0-0003484382900031-main.pdf).

As far as MLTT with induction-recursion or induction-induction, I don't know what the situation is, and AFAIK, the problem of exact consistency strength is still open.

Comment: So in a sense, system F is a very weak theory, but it has this combinatorial problem which requires a very strong theory to prove? If that's the case, then shouldn't its proof theoretic ordinal be known, and less than $\epsilon_0$, contradicting the question that I linked?

Comment: And should it read "if $p$ is normalizing, then $p\not\Vdash\emptyset$?

Comment: Why do you mean by "in $\mathrm{HA}_\omega$ all functions *must* be computable"? Certainly not, consider the set-theoretic model.

Comment: @fhyve: I meant $p\not\Vdash\bot$ rather than $p\not\Vdash\phi$. Corrected

Comment: @fhyve System F doesn't have a proof theoretic ordinal, *per se*, since it isn't even a theory of arithmetic, just a quantified propositional logic. In this sense it is indeed a very weak theory. It's strength comes from the fact that as a *programing language*, it may serve as a language of realizers for higher-order arithmetic.

Comment: @AndrejBauer certainly, all functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ which can be proven to exist within $\mathrm{HA}_\omega$ are computable (from the "outside"). Of course, from the "inside", it is consistent to assume that there are non-computable functions, unless further fun axioms are added.

Comment: Then you should have said something like "definable functions in $\mathrm{HA}_\omega$ are computable". Saying "must be computable" is at least misleading.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll amend the post.

Comment: You don't say much about what it takes to prove normalization of MLTT + inductive types. Do you know much about that? If not, I can accept your answer and ask that in a separate question

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with MLTT +/- Nat, W-types, and 1 or n universes. After that, then maybe $\omega$ or more universes, induction-induction, and the like.